# related to tense agreement

Tags: past-tense, tense-agreement

Shouldn't be agreement of tenses be applied in this case?

We **learnt** enough to (**pass** vs **passed**) the exam.

Comment: No, because in a phrasing like "learnt to ____" you use the bare infinitive, not a conjugated form.  Think of it this way: in a sentence like "I learned to cook", the learning is in the past; the cooking is not in the past, it's just a general activity with no time reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. The word *to* requires an infinitive but you can use the past tense with a conjunction.

- We learnt enough to pass.
- We learnt enough and passed.
- We didn't learn enough and failed.
- We tried hard but failed.